# Best way to update certain columns of table in SQL Server based on Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a table on SQL Server that looks like this, where each row has a unique combination of `Event A` and `Event B`.

```
`Global Rules Table

ID   Event 1  |  Event 2  |  Validated as |  Generated as  |   Generated with score 
1      EA1       EB1           Rule            Anti-Rule            0.01
2      EA1       EB2           Rule            Rule                 0.95  
3      ...       ...           ...             ...                  ...
```

I have another table with a Foreign Key constraint to `Global Rules Table` called `Local Rules Table`.

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this

```
      Event 1  |  Event 2  |  Validated as |  Generated as  |   Generated with score 
        EA1       EB1           Rule            Rule                 0.85
        EA1       EB2           Rule            Rule                 0.95  
        ...       ...           ...             ...                  ...
```

Since I have this Foreign Key constraint between `Local Rules` and `Global Rules` tables I can't use `df.to_sql('Global Rules',con,if_exists='replace')`.

The columns which I want to update in the database based on values in dataframe are `Generated as` and `Generated with score`, so what is the best way to only update those columns in database table based on the DataFrame I have? Is there some out of the box function or library which I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a library to accomplish this. I started writing one myself to host on PyPi but haven't finished yet.

An inner join against an SQL temporary table works well in this case. It will only update a subset of columns in SQL and can be efficient for updating many records.

I assume you are using pyodbc for the connection to SQL server.

### SQL Cursor

```py
# quickly stream records into the temp table
cursor.fast_executemany = True
```

### Create Temporary Table

```
# assuming your DataFrame also has the ID column to perform the SQL join
statement = "CREATE TABLE [#Update_Global Rules Table] (ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, [Generated as] VARCHAR(200), [Generated with score] FLOAT)"
cursor.execute(statement)
```

### Insert DataFrame into a Temporary Table

```py
# insert only the key and the updated values
subset = df[['ID','Generated as','Generated with score']]

# form SQL insert statement
columns = ", ".join(subset.columns)
values = '('+', '.join(['?']*len(subset.columns))+')'

# insert
statement = "INSERT INTO [#Update_Global Rules Table] ("+columns+") VALUES "+values
insert = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]

cursor.executemany(statement, insert)
```

### Update Values in Main Table from Temporary Table

```py
statement = '''
UPDATE
     [Global Rules Table]
SET
     u.Name
FROM
     [Global Rules Table] AS t
INNER JOIN 
     [#Update_Global Rules Table] AS u 
ON
     u.ID=t.ID;
'''

cursor.execute(statement)
```

### Drop Temporary Table

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE [#Update_Global Rules Table]")
```

Comment: It throws an error pyodbc.DataError: ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range (0) (SQLExecute)'). Do you have to modify something in order to allow NaN values all columns except for id?

Comment: NaN values, or any other missing values such as pd.NaT, first need to be changed to the standard Python None data type.

Comment: The error you listed makes me think there may be another issue, although I haven't tested. It may be that the "Generated with score" column in SQL is defined as a decimal type but you are attempting to write a float to it. Essentially, in Python more decimal places are being generated than the SQL column can accept.

Comment: I had to replace the np.nan values with None values, that solved it.